# Unable to scp over ssh in python

Tags: python, ssh, scp

Problem statement:

I have 3 different hub's(Hub1,Hub2 & Hub3). I need to copy files from Hub1 -> Hub2 -> Hub3 (there is no direct connection from Hub1 to Hub3, We need to transfer via Hub2 only).

So, Here I'm running my python script in Hub1 and doing ssh in script. By doing this I will be virtually(i,e script exec in Hub1 but flow of exec is in Hub2 after SSH)  in Hub2 and trying to do scp over there like below:

```
ssh_stdin,ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("scp %s tusrname@100.101.102.3:/home/tpath/tdir" %(imageName))
```

While executing  above command it has to prompt for password, unfortunately everything is directed into  ssh_stderr channel.

How Can I do scp over ssh  or how can I give ssh_stdin.

Any other solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pysftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp) as following:

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('100.101.102.3',username='username', password='passwd') as sftp:
        sftp.put('filename')
```

Comment: pysftp works If I am directly transferring file from HUB2 to HUB 3, Here the real challange is script runs in HUB 1 and virtually interacts with HUB 2 via SSH and there we need transfer file to HUB3.

Comment: You could do it in two steps: 1) first copy the script (which includes pysftp for copying from HUB2 > HUB3) to HUB2, 2) then login to HUB2 via ssh and execute that script.